# Create a private folder in Android: set the SELinux attribute of a folder in external storage

Tags: adb, security, sd-card, privacy, selinux

There are quite a few apps that require read and write access to the external storage, which gives them access to the whole /sdcard directory. But since that is also the only storage the user themselves have access to, is there any way to create a folder there under /sdcard (maybe even inside /sdcard/Download/) that is restricted to a few apps specified by the user such that no other app has access to it?

I imagine this is something possible within the scope of SELinux, and might only be possible to set up with root access, although should still be usable without enabling root access once set up properly.

According to [1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/file_contexts) and [2](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1), it seems `mkdir /sdcard/private` then create a new context `user_private` for it that is also assigned to trusted apps one by one. But I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: it looks intuitive, but in fact it not possible

Comment: Can you be more specific with references why it would be not possible?